# What happens to an x86/x64 computer when its processor reaches maximum temperature?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, cooling, overheating

I recently found out that x86/x64 processors have a maximum temperature defined in their spec sheet. In the spec sheet the "maximum temperature" is referred to as the "Core Tjmax".

For example on an Intel Core i7-620M you can see the spec sheet [here](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/specupdate/322814.pdf) if you search for "Core Tjmax" you will see that this model has a maximum temperature of 105°C.

**What happens to an x86/x64 computer when its processor reaches "maximum temperature" or "Core Tjmax"?**

Comment: I can assure you my PC, I have an i7, turns off long before it reaches 105 degrees.

Comment: back in the day, this sort of thing used to happen http://www.phys.ncku.edu.tw/~htsu/humor/fry_egg.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer:**

The CPU asserts the PROCHOT pin and turns itself off.

It is up to the motherboard to act (or not) on that signal.

**Longer answer**

When the CPU gets hot (but has not yet reached emergency shutdown temperature) it will throttle itself. That means it will lower the multiplier and the voltage. As a result processing  get slower but the CPU also generated less heat.

If that fails and temperature rises to then it will reach a point where the CPU asserts the PROCHOT pin and it does a full shutdown of the CPU.

More details can be found on intels site. Look for your specific CPU and select the correct datasheet. ( E.g.  [This one](http://download.intel.com/design/processor/datashts/322812.pdf) for some of their mobile CPU's)

AMDs  x86/amd64's chips do something similar. (As do all modern CPUs)

Comment: When the CPU signals with the PROCHOT, the motherboard is the one who cuts power to the entire machine? The PROCHOT signal and the motherboard shutdown happen outside of the OS' visibility? and thus prevent the OS from catching the signal and doing something with it?

Comment: The motherboard is **allowed** to do that. If it does that or not is up to the designer. And PROCHOT can be set as an bidirectional signal (meaning the motherboard can also detect overheating and signal the CPU) rather than the default unidirectional signal (where the CPU asserts the signal to indicate that it will shutdown and where the rest of the MB may follow suit).

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith: What would/could the OS do?

Comment: If gets an ACPI signal of overheating? Either shut down right now (damn data integrety and save the hardware) or send a shutdown now signal the the OS with a very short timeout, after which it should fall back to hard poweroff.

Answer (score 1):

The processor will throttle itself (PROCHOT# is signaled) once you reach that temperature. The motherboard may or may not choose to shut the machine down at this point, but there's generally still a chance to gracefully shut down. The operating system may choose to do so when it detects an overheating condition (Linux will shut down with `Critical temperature reached (### C), shutting down.`). However, some motherboards may simply power down right away, perhaps even before this temperature is reached.

If you go too far past that point, the THERMTRIP# signal is asserted and the processor halts all execution. The motherboard is expected to turn the machine off immediately. From [the *Skylake-S* datasheet](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/desktop-6th-gen-core-family-datasheet-vol-1.pdf), page 86:

> Reaching the maximum operating temperature activates the Thermal Control Circuit (TCC). When activated the TCC causes both the processor IA core and graphics core to reduce frequency and voltage adaptively. The Adaptive Thermal Monitor will remain active as long as the package temperature remains at its specified limit. Therefore, the Adaptive Thermal Monitor will continue to reduce the package frequency and voltage until the TCC is de-activated.

Page 89:

> PROCHOT# (processor hot) is asserted by the processor when the TCC is active. Only a single PROCHOT# pin exists at a package level. When any DTS temperature reaches the TCC activation temperature, the PROCHOT# signal will be asserted. PROCHOT# assertion policies are independent of Adaptive Thermal Monitor enabling.

Page 90:

> Regardless of enabling the automatic or on-demand modes, in the event of a catastrophic cooling failure, the package will automatically shut down when the silicon has reached an elevated temperature that risks physical damage to the product. At this point the THERMTRIP# signal will go active.

Page 109 says that the critical shutdown point for *Skylake-S* is about 130 °C at the junction.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers go into what happens technically - though they're missing a few minor things that's probably worth posting as part of an answer.

"TJ" probably refers to a thermal probe, likely a thermocouple,(with the J standing for junction) though it might be a thermistor. Essentially there's a small thermometer in your processor, and your processor will throttle down when it overheats.

Its been almost a decade but its worth looking at what happens if the CPU didn't throttle or shut down to protect itself. AMD didn't and the processors would start [smoking and cook themselves](https://youtu.be/BSGcnRanYMM?t=60) - going up to 300 degress celsius. While there's a 'maximum' safe temperature your processor should throttle down and/or shut down well before that